# 302 response in flutter

Tags: android, ios, http, flutter

I developed an application with native android and native iOS, but now I want to recreate it using flutter.

some of the requests that I done successfully in native android and iOS are returning 302 status code in flutter.

the problem is that I can't get 302 response on postman so I may understand what is the problem, it keep happening only on flutter.

```
  Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Authorization": "Bearer ${App.token}"};

  Response response = await post(URL, body: jsonEncode({"FullName": name}), headers: headers);
  if (checkIfSuccessful(response)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: You should set the `followRedirects` property to false in your HttpClientRequest.

Comment: @Benjamin already tried that. Didn’t help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter **DevTools** to inspect the network; get it in the android studio by pressing [this icon](https://share.getcloudapp.com/WnuJ7l8z)

enter network tab and begin recording, you should be able to analyze network traffic and understand the problem

in your code you can check for response status code like

```
Response response = await post(URL, body: jsonEncode({"FullName": name}), headers: headers);
switch (response.statusCode){
  case (200){
    print('Ok');
    break;
  }
  case (302){
    print('Handling redirect');
    break;
  }
}
```